# Bisect / Cut Along Vertices That Are Selected?

Tags: bisect

Is there a way to select a group of vertices and perform a bisect/cut along them?  For instance if I drew a car's body, but want to then cut out the door so that it can open, what do I need to do to accomplish that?  Should I just select all the vertices and hit "P" to make them their own object or something?

Comment: you could draw the door shape on the surface with the knife, then use V to rip this part of your mesh so that it is a separate mesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Bisect operator]

There is a Bisect Operator that might do what you want it to.

*3D View* > *Mesh* > *Bisect*, requires a Face Selection

This allows you to split the mesh along a plane you can define by dragging, or numerically. If your Operator Panel is not open, hit F6 to show it. It come with a bunch of useful options, like

Fill, which fills the cut edges with faces
Clear Inner/Outer which remove one or both sides of the cut
Axis Threshold that gives the cut adge some fuzzines in where the cut-off happens.

If your vertices are already defining you cutting edge, it would be more efficient to simply separate the part into its own mesh by selecting it and hitting <kbd>P</kbd> to do *Separate* > *Selection*